# Sum of the entries in the matrix $A^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\neq I$ be a $5\times5$ matrix with real entries such that the sum of the entries in each row of $A$ is $1$. Then the sum of all the entries in $A^3$ is

1)$\space 3$ $\qquad $2)$\space 15$ $\qquad$ 3)$\space 5$ $\qquad$ 4)$\space 125$

**Solution:**

The answer is $5$ if $A = I$, but for $A \neq I$,

I found that vectors
$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and 
$\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
-1\\
-1\\
-1\\
-1\\
\end{pmatrix}$ 
are eigen vectors for the matrix $A$ corresponding to eigen value $1$.
From here, I dont know how to proceed, please help me solve the question..and if there are mistakes in my argument, please tell me..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $e$ be the all one vector.

As you pointed out, we have $Ae=e$

The sum of all the entries in $A^3$ is

$$e^TA^3e=e^TA^2(Ae)=e^TA^2e=e^TAe=e^Te=n$$

where $n$ is equal to 5 for this particular question.

Comment: Great...explanation...Thank you SiongthyeGoh

Comment: Really not a fan of using **e** to describe vectors which aren't a standard unit. A ones vector is easier as **1**.