# Sum of all entries of $A^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $5\times5$ matrix with real entries such that the sum of the entries in each row of $A$ is $1$. Then the sum of all entries in $A^3$ is

(a) $3$

(b) $15$

(c) $5$

(d) $125$

$1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, that's all I know. How could we go to the sum of all entries of $A^3$ ?

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1796331/sum-of-the-entries-in-the-matrix-a3?rq=1

Comment: yes, it is. I am sorry

Answer (score 3):

The sum of all entries of each row being $1$ is equivalent to the fact that $(1,1,\dots,1)$ is an eigenvector of $A$, with eigenvalue $1$. Then $(1,1,\dots,1)$ is also an eigenvector of $A^3$, with eigenvalue $1^3=1$; hence the sum of the elements of each row of $A^3$ is also $1$. Thus the sum of all the entries of $A^3$ is the number of rows, i.e. $5$.